# Detecting HID Proximity Card by using NFC

Tags: android, tags, interop, nfc, rfid

I want to implement a functionality in which an Android device can detect the HID ProxCard II using NFC.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

The HID Prox system operates at a carrier frequency of 125 kHz. NFC operates at 13.56 MHz. Consequently, it's impossible to read HID Prox cards with an NFC reader.

Comment: But if you will android HCE, the android device can act as HID tag which can we read by RFID reader. So I think vice versa should also possible.

Comment: Android HCE (NFC card emulation) can't be used to emulate HID Prox tags either. Note that you specifically asked for the HID **Prox** product family. There are some HID products (both cards and readers) that do indeed operate on the same frequency and even share protocols with NFC. Some of these other HID products **can** be used with Android NFC devices.

Comment: check the link <link>https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/hid-prox-br-en.pdf</link> MIFARE/PROX card also operate on 125 khz and it can be detected by deivce nfc.

Comment: @ishanjain MIFARE/Prox are hybrid cards made of a Prox chip (+antenna) and a MIFARE chip (+ antenna). The MIFARE product family operates on 13.56 MHz and shares protocols with NFC. Consequently, the MIFARE chip can be read by some NFC devices. Nevertheless, this does not apply to the HID Prox chip.

Comment: Hi all, I have NFC tags. Will it be possible to read my tags by the HID Proximity readers?